# How to obtain the [CLS] sentence embedding of multiple sentences successively without facing a RAM crash?

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory, tokenize, bert-language-model

I would like to obtain the [CLS] token's sentence embedding (as it represents the whole sentence's meaning) using BERT. I have many sentences (about 40) that belong to a Document, and 246 such documents in the form of a dictionary shown below.

{'DocNo': 1,
'Text': 'Learned counsel for the Appellants-Revenue Mr.E.I.Sanmathi submits that he does not press the substantial question of law No.1.',
'Embedding': [],
'Labels': 'ARG_PETITIONER'},

```
I have a python list, named rows_list ([]) which contains multiple such dictionaries - for the sentences present in the Documents. 
I need to obtain the sentence embedding for each of these sentences and add them as the value to the 'Embedding' key. 
I am using Google Colab's free version.
```

```
for row in rows_list:
  if row["DocNo"] != 1:
    tokenizedText = tokenizer(row['Text'], padding='max_length', max_length=512, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
    outputs = model(**tokenizedText, output_hidden_states=True)
    last_hidden_states = outputs.hidden_states[-1]
    row["Embedding"] = last_hidden_states[0,0,:]
  else:
    break;
```

```
This is the code I wrote for doing the same. I first tried to run the for loop as a whole, without the if-else : but came across the error - **Your session crashed after using all available RAM. **

I got the same error even when I wanted to obtain the embeddings for 1 Document. 
How do I ensure that I receive the embeddings for each sentence throughtout all the documents without facing the RAM issue?
```